# AfterUpdate triggered on insert

Tags: apex, trigger, after-trigger

This issue occurred few days ago. When I create Account, both AfterInsert and AfterUpdate triggers are executed. I disabled AfterInsert trigger, however despite this AfterUpdate trigger was executed, so there is not updating in the AfterInsertTrigger.

In AfterUpdate I can see what fields are updating:

```
 CreatedDate=null
 CreatedById=null
 LastModifiedDate=null
 LastModifiedById=null
 SystemModstamp=null
 CustomerSince__c=null

 CreatedDate=2017-08-08 10:41:27
 CreatedById=0057E0000012qtHQAQ
 LastModifiedDate=2017-08-08 10:41:28
 LastModifiedById=0057E0000012qtHQAQ
 SystemModstamp=2017-08-08 10:41:28
 CustomerSince__c=2017-08-08 00:00:00
```

However I would expect these fields to be 'initialised' on insert and not triggering the update event. I don't know about any implementation change or workflow rule on our side which could cause this. Did someone experience something like this? I would be grateful for any hint how to solve this situation.

Comment: Do you have any `Workflow Rules`? `Process Builder` flows?

Answer (score 1):

The order of execution is like this:

```
1) System Validation rule (required field, field format) (SV)
2) Before Triggers are executed (BT)
3) Custom Validation rules are checked (CV)
4) After Triggers are executed (AT)
5) Assignment Rules are executed (AR)
6) Auto-Response Rules are executed (ARR)
7) Workflow Rules are executed (WR)
8) Before and after triggers are executed one more time if the workflow rule updates a field (BT & AT)
9) Escalation Rules are executed (ER)
10) Parent Rollup Summary Formula or Cross Object Formula fields are updated in the respective objects. (RSF, COF) (These parent records also goes through the entire execution order)
11) Criteria Based Sharing rules are evaluated (CBS)
12) Any Post-Commit Logic is executed (PCL)  (like sending an email)
```

Hence the AfterInsertTrigger would be getting called. And there will be a workflow/Process Builder related to the object which might be triggering a field updated which will call  AfterUpdate. 
Hence to know the full execution try setting the debug logs to finest. And you can observe the debug logs to see which workflow is getting executed.

Do you know how to set debug logs and debug level to finest.?

If not then click here :  [Debug Setup](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=code_add_users_debug_log.htm&type=0)